# Is Docker installation essential for VIKTOR installation

Tags: installation

Is Docker installation essential for VIKTOR installation? I am confused because VIKTOR says in its guidance that "CAUTION
This document explains the installation procedure to run VIKTOR using Docker, which is not recommended for first-time users. Prefer to follow the normal installation instructions." But no explanation on how to install VIKTOR without Docker.

I am trying to install without Docker but it does not work